# How to use vue.js syntax inside a string template with dropzone.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, dropzone.js, vue-component

I am currently trying to implement `dropzone.js` [Doc Ref](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) - into my application. But since i've managed to run the basic functionallity of dropzone.js

I want to customize the `preview-template` to hide and show the upload progressbar during different application state.

I can customize the `preview-template` by passing an html string to the options object during initialization of the `dropzone` instance. As stated in the `dropzone.js` docs But obviously the `vue` syntax is not going to be processed if i simply sprinkle it over this html string. It somehow has to be processed to implement the thing.

## Problem:

What i wanna do is to use `vue.js` syntax inside this preview-template.
This is the component i'm talking about.

## Code:

```
<dropzone id="myVueDropzone" :use-custom-dropzone-options=true
          :dropzoneOptions="dzOptions"
          :url="photosForm.uploadImageUrl"
          v-on:vdropzone-removed-file="deleteImage"
          :preview-template="templatePreview"
          v-on:vdropzone-success="showSuccess">
</dropzone>
```

## Vue-Script Code:

```
import Dropzone from 'vue2-dropzone';
export default {

    methods: {

        templatePreview(){
            return `
                    <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
                      <div class="dz-image" style="width: 200px;height: 180px">
                          <img data-dz-thumbnail />
                      </div>
                      <div class="dz-details">
                        <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size></span></div>
                        <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
                      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
                      <div class="dz-success-mark"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                      <div class="dz-error-mark"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <select class="form-control" title="" name="image_type">
                            <options v-for="type in image_type" value="type.value">{{ type.title }}</options>
                        </select>
                    </div>
              `;
        }
    },
}
```

[Github Resource](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone), [Github Issue](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone/issues/143)

**Author of library says,**

> Unfortunately what your wanting to do isn't easily achievable at the moment, although it would be nice. We're currently planning a bit of a rewrite of this module so we'll see if we can work out how to bake this in. [Here](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone/issues/143)

Comment: You can't use Vue in the preview template, you have to hide the dropzone's built in preview and then manually iterate over the files with `v-for` ;}

Comment: @Slim Yes i have to do something like that, but it will not shown in dropzone area and also i want that thing dynamic and reactive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot apply Vue in the build in preview template, since dropzone internally manipulates the DOM. But you may... In your `mounted` hook:

```
new Vue({

    data() {
        return {
            files: []
        }
    },

    mounted(){
        var vm = this;

        // create your dropzone instance using reference to the target div
        var dz = new Dropzone(vm.$refs.dropzone /*, { opts }*/);

        // update data.files whenever new files are added
        dz.on('addedfiles', function(files){

            // convert files (an array like object) to real array
            files = Array.from(files);

            // add some additional properties (link, accepted...) 
            // before files are registered to the `vm` instance
            // so that Vue may convert them into reactive
            files.forEach( file => file.link = file.accepted = undefined);

            // files now may be added to `vm`;
            vm.files = files;
        });
    }
})
```

Now files are reactive and you may use them with `v-for` in your template:

```
<template>
    <div>
        // this is the dropzone area
        <div ref="dropzone"></div>

        // list the files
        <p v-for="file in files"> {{file.name}} </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

You may use other Dropzone events to bind additional info to your reactive data that you may use in the template.